# Review window (without edit privs) silently fails on attempts to edit when another is pending

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

Was doing [this Server Fault Late Answer review](https://serverfault.com/review/late-answers/353630) and I wanted to edit the question. The edit link appeared broken (clicking the link did nothing) so I reloaded. Still nothing. I simply selected "No Action" and figured I'd just go edit it directly in the question.

Upon going to the answer and attempting to edit, the problem became clearer

[image]

So it appears that something is up with this notice in the review window. I can't reproduce it to check if it's something simpler. To recap

1. Visit the Late Answer or First Post queue where you have no edit privs
2. Find a review with a pending edit
3. Attempt to edit

Using Firefox 57.0.4